# PHP 7 FTP extension is not loaded in Windows 7

Tags: php, windows-7, ftp

I recently install PHP 7 in Windows 7 OS (32 bit). I used FTP library nicolab/php-ftp-client for FTP functions and I getting an exception as

> Fatal error: Uncaught FtpClient\FtpException: FTP extension is not
>   loaded! in

And I see the code, there is

```
if (!extension_loaded('ftp')) {
    throw new FtpException('FTP extension is not loaded!');
}
```

So I checked the loaded extension by php

```
C:\Users\Tamil>php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
filter
gd
hash
iconv
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
soap
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

There is no ftp extension. But in PHP site http://php.net/manual/en/ftp.installation.php

> The Windows version of PHP has built-in support for this extension.
>   You do not need to load any additional extensions in order to use
>   these functions.

I restart the apache many times. Still FTP exception error shown. Could you please guide me to solve this issues.

The PHP version is

```
C:\Users\Tamil>php -v
PHP 7.0.0 (cli) (built: Dec  3 2015 11:36:59) (ZTS ) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A quick test on my system shows the same problem:

```
C:\>php -v
PHP 7.0.0 (cli) (built: Dec  3 2015 11:36:58) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.0RC2, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans

C:\>php --ri ftp
Extension 'ftp' not present.
```

Looking in the `ext` folder shows a `php_ftp.dll`.  Enabling this in `php.ini` and rerunning the above gives:

```
C:\>php --ri ftp

ftp

FTP support => enabled
FTPS support => enabled
```

So, enable the extension and you'll be fine.

Comment: enable is done by adding `extension=php_ftp.dll` anywhere in php.ini