# PHP 7.0.5: Use of undefined constant FTP_BINARY - assumed 'FTP_BINARY'

Tags: windows, iis, laravel-5.1, php-7, flysystem

Upgrading to PHP 7.0.5 on Windows IIS (finally since the sqlsrv PDO drivers are available). I'm using Laravel 5.1 and when trying to connect to an FTP drive I get the following error from https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/blob/master/src/Adapter/Ftp.php#L19.

`Use of undefined constant FTP_BINARY - assumed 'FTP_BINARY'`

This is a PHP constant for the transfer, so shouldn't have a problem and there's nothing in the docs to say it's deprecated or anything. FTP_ASCII is the same. The only thing i've done is change the PHP version + SQL drivers.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Turns out that FTP is not turned on in PHP7 by default and has an extension that php5.6 doesn't have:
[PHP 7 FTP extension is not loaded in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173996/php-7-ftp-extension-is-not-loaded-in-windows-7)

Comment: This is being addressed in https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupFlysystemBundle/issues/118